# Simply post to facebook by an url with basically html

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 3 buttons to share some news with social services. I want something very simply that works basically in html (the ... stuff is dinamic):

```
<a target="_blank" href="?">
    <div class="fb-button button"></div>
</a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=...">
    <div class="tw-button button"></div>
</a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=...&media=...">
    <div class="pi-button button"></div>
</a>
```

There is something in facebook that I could use as href, an url to a post interface or something? As I suppose the answer could be 'no', what would be the proper solution? I don't want a standard like button, I don't want customize the like button with css and I don't want to develop a post call with javascript because I really want that the user recieves a window (or popup or something) where he can customize the content of the post before accepting it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I clicked on a share button in Wordpress to share my blog via Facebook, it opened a window with the following URL:

> http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwp.me%2Fpz9a5-dO&t=Training+Bulletin+180

So, I would guess you could simply use sharer.php and set your website as the value of "u" in the href you create.so perhaps the first line of code would be:

> a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmylink.com%2Fpage.htm"